# Detect frame change or re-run content script on frame reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, frame

I am working on executing some code on a [particular website](http://tempostorm.com) via a Chrome Extension. My code is supposed to execute only executes on certain pages of the site. This includes calling pageAction.show ONLY on certain pages, and content scripts only on certain pages.

When linked to a page directly - everything works fine. However, if I navigate via any other page to one where my script should execute and pageAction.show should fire - it doesn't. I believe this has to do with how the page is loaded from within site navigation. I was wondering if there was a way to detect a reload/refresh and "force" my script to fire. Otherwise, best practice would be appreciated here. Thanks!

***EDIT:*** I don't think it's an iFrame. I'm not even if sure if "Frame" is the right word. The website just has a... very dynamic loading method? Not sure what the proper term would be, but whatever it is, it's fucking with my code bigtime.

***EDIT 2:*** Experiencing some unexpected (to me) behavior. When the content script loads with this (pastebin.com/c7m3wXcf) code, nothing happens. But if I refresh and then navigate around, it starts to fire. But it simply refuses to do so the first time around. Perhaps there's something important I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for Mutation Observers:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.documentElement;

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // put your code here "pageAction.show" 
    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

---

What this code does it observes the DOM Tree and if there are any changes like creation/deletion of dom node, it executes the code.

Comment: I don't think it's an iFrame. I'm not even if sure if "Frame" is the right word. The website just has a... very dynamic loading method? Not sure what the proper term would be.

Comment: I guess you want to check if anything has been changed in the dom tree.

Comment: Experiencing some unexpected (to me) behavior. When the content script loads with this (http://pastebin.com/c7m3wXcf) code, nothing happens. But if I refresh and then navigate around, it starts to fire. But it simply refuses to do so the first time around. Perhaps there's something important I'm missing here.